# how to count values of coulmn of tables

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have two tables following:

**tbl_employee:**

```
id

full_name
```

---

**tbl_performance:**

```
id

emp_id(fk)

innovator   (here emp_id will come)

outstanding_performer (here emp_id will come)
```

---

Now I want to count all innovator employees and outstanding performers from above tables using mysql query without using any sub query.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You mean the records count?

Comment: First of all explain us why there are three columns for emp_id in tbl_performance table. What is the purpose and what data goes in that table

Comment: want to count how many employees are innovator and how many outstanding performers using voting panel

Comment: you can do it in only one column(can be named  for eg. special_employees) and set flags for it like 1: innovator, 2: outstanding_performer. It will be better for you instead of having two different columns for same kind of thing

Comment: no table is already working and have good no of records

Comment: Where does tbl_employee come into it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might just need conditional aggregation.

```
MariaDB [sandbox]> drop table if exists tbl_performance;
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.11 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]> create table tbl_performance (id int,emp_id int, innovator int, oustanding_performer int);
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.32 sec)

MariaDB [sandbox]>
MariaDB [sandbox]> insert into tbl_performance values
    -> (1,1,1,1), (2,2,2,null),(3,3,null,3);
Query OK, 3 rows affected (0.03 sec)
Records: 3  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

MariaDB [sandbox]> select emp_id,
    -> sum(case when innovator is not null then 1 else 0 end) innovators,
    -> sum(case when oustanding_performer is not null then 1 else 0 end) oustanding_performers
    -> from tbl_performance
    -> group by emp_id with rollup;
+--------+------------+-----------------------+
| emp_id | innovators | oustanding_performers |
+--------+------------+-----------------------+
|      1 |          1 |                     1 |
|      2 |          1 |                     0 |
|      3 |          0 |                     1 |
|   NULL |          2 |                     2 |
+--------+------------+-----------------------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: what we do if column by default value is 0 "not null"

Comment: Change is not null to <> 0

Comment: Best if you post how you expect your result to look because I am not at all clear what you are looking for.

Comment: how many innovaters and outstanding count for and employee its employees data or counting employee wise